# Blank Screen After Suspend (or when screen auto turns off) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, screen

I have fresh installed 16.04 LTS, and have reinstalled several times.  Whenever the screen turns off or computer is suspended, nothing will bring it back on except a hard reset.

I have an Asus ROG GL502VM with a NVIDIA GTX 1060.  I've tried editing the with the nomodeset thing, and was thinking of installing the NVIDIA drivers, but can't find how to install them for the GTX 1060.  (Also from other users it appears after installing NVIDIA drivers Ubuntu bricks.)

At any rate, I'm trying to find a solid solution to getting the screen to turn back on, because leaving the screen on and Ubuntu unlocked at all times is not reasonable.  I've searched for solutions up and down the web and this site and nothing seems to work.

Please help

Comment: Are you using a displayport cable? If yes, can you try an HDMI instead?

Comment: Check for any ACPI error/problem with `dmesg | grep -i acpi`.